# How to $watch a field in a factory angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind

I'm using a `factory` in my web app. In the `factory` there's an object `mapLayers`. In my `controller` I assign this `factory.mapLayers` object to a variable on the scope `$scope.mapLayers`, and I'm using `ngRepeat` on it.

The problem is that changes that happens in `factory.mapLayers` doesn't affect `$scope.mapLayers` and so the `DOM` doesn't display the new changes.
How can I `$watch` or bind my `$factory.mapLayers` to `factory.mapLayers`?

mapService.js:

```
...
factory.mapLayers = [];
...
return factory;
```

mainController.js:

```
...
$scope.mapLayers = MapService.mapLayers;
...
```

main.html:

```
...
<div ng-repeat="layer in mapLayers">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Sure there's a way. But you have to start wondering if you shouldn't use `$rootScope` for storage that needs to be data binded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must register a watcher on the variable. Put this into your controller:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(
    function () {
        return MapService.mapLayers;
    }, function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
        // the `scope` parameter refers to the current scope
        scope.mapLayers = MapService.mapLayers 
    }
)
```

The first argument to `$watchCollection()` is a function that returns a value to be watched (could also be a string that is evaluated as Angular expression), and the second is a callback that is called when a change is detected.

It's worth mentioning that `$watch()` might not work (depending on how you change your array) as it will only be checking whether the array reference has been changed  - the latter happens, for example, if you assign `MapService.mapLayers` to a new Array object.

`$watchCollection`, on the other hand, will also watch for the changes in the *contents* of the array, i.e. it will detect changes like adding or removing items. For a more detailed explanation, you might also want to see Ben Nadel's great [blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm) on the differences between the two.

Comment: That's great, good to hear that! ||| One word of caution though - be careful to not overuse $watches in your application, because Angular checks for the changes in every $digest cycle and if it has too many values to check, you might start experiencing slowdowns and sluggish performance.

Comment: As I understand it, it doesn't matter if I set the `mapLayers` on the $rootScope or in a $watch, since every $digest cycle will go over this array. Am I right?

Comment: If you add it to a scope (e.g. $rootScope) and change it there, digest cycle will detect that, yes (a watcher is created automatically by Angular for every scope value). However, that might not be the best solution from the application architecture's point of view. Just imagine, for example, how would it look like if you put every shared data object into $rootScope. Therefore it's usually better to hold data where it logically belongs.

Comment: Yes as for the architecture logic I agree with you that it should be placed in a specified element. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should `$watch` the service variable in your controller.

mainController.js:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return MapService.mapLayers },function() {
    $scope.mapLayers = MapService.mapLayers 
})
```